# import existing project to maven multi module parent project

Tags: maven-3, myeclipse

I have 3 projects, action, security and service, I would like to make into a multi module maven project.

First I did is to create a parent project - actionParent, change packaging to pom, add 
Next I add  into each project.

But the problem is child project does not show up in the parent project

such as

```
actionParent
     |
      ----action
     |
      ----security
     |
      ----service
     |
      ----pom.xml
```

Right click parent project do import existing maven project did not do the trick, I am using myEclipse 10

Answer (score 1):

Is this similar to the problem you're having? The answer is pretty verbose, it might help.

[Maven - making child projects that can be independent of their parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725579/maven-making-child-projects-that-can-be-independent-of-their-parent)