# maven skip/ignore parent tag

Tags: maven

I wonder if it is possible to ignore parent tag in the pom.xml file. I need this because I have the following situation:

the structure is:

- super root pom

  - root pom

    - module1 pom
    - module2 pom

      - module2.1 pom
      - module2.2 pom
      - module2.3 pom

I need to set **super root pom** as parent pom for **root pom** to make it availible to build it specifically on build server, but the trick is, that I don't have **super root pom** locally and need to ignore parent tag or do something not to be dependent on super parent pom. So, for example,  I need to run **root pom** clean install independently from the super root pom. Is there any way to do this using some parameters or some pom.xml tricks?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Please, take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725579/maven-making-child-projects-that-can-be-independent-of-their-parent

Comment: @defaultlocale, I saw this topic, but there is no answer for my case. I'm, actually, not sure if it is possible at all.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. [romaintaz's answer's first part](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1728006/451518) states that's not possible too and gives an explanation (inheritance). I guess you have to import super root pom into local directory or use some scripting to change your poms on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a corporate repo (Nexus, Artifactory...) The simpler would be to mvn deploy your parent, to make it available for all your projects, all your team, with no need of a local (relative file system path) relationship.