# IntelliJ directory little blue dot label in maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea

So I'm working on a java/scala maven project in IntelliJ. I made a new directory, and filled it out with src and test stuff, but it's not behaving the same as other directories.

[image]

What does the little blue square mean? Is it important? How do I make my new directory (second one) behave the same?

Thanks in advance, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means the folder is defined as an Intellij Module.

Complete list of Intellij icons: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html

Comment: Is there a way to mark an existing icon as an Intellij Module?

Comment: Actually it showed up on its own eventually, probably because I have an IML in there.

Comment: @Inbl:To mark an existing Maven Module as an Intellij Module then in the Maven Projects do 'Add Maven Projects' (the green plus). You will not achieve the same in doing a new import maven module because the Maven module is already there but not seen as an Intellij module. IMHO this one deserves its own SO question.

Comment: what is the reason that Intellij doesn't load the module although it described as module in parent pom?

Comment: Right-click on your .iml file and press the "import module" option to get this icon to show up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the entry in the parent build script about the new project that is available. Currently, build script is not aware of the child project.
if you are using multiproject

[Maven - making child projects that can be independent of their parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725579/maven-making-child-projects-that-can-be-independent-of-their-parent)

Another thing is mark an existing Maven Module as an Intellij Module then in the Maven Projects do 'Add Maven Projects' (the green plus).